# pyqtgraph : using AxisItem to plot time axis displaying extra axis

Tags: pyqt, time-series, pyqtgraph

When I implemented a time axis class overriding AxisItem class it is displaying an extra axis on the top of the window. How can I make that axis disappear? You can see image of this issue on [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyqtgraph/pSIn0xNGodA/VsM9-3NJDZAJ).

Or here is the simple code

```
 from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
 import pyqtgraph as pg
 from PySide.QtCore import QTime
 class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
     def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
         return [QTime().addMSecs(value).toString('mm:ss') for value    in values]
 app = QtGui.QApplication([])
 win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
 axis = TimeAxisItem('bottom')
 plot = win.addPlot(title = "sdf",axisItems={'bottom':axis})
 curve = plot.plot()
 QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

I'd be very glad for your help.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug!
This has been fixed in the latest develop branch on github; will appear in the next release.